# How to include bootstrap in Wordpress plugin development?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, include, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am developing the plugin, and I would like to include bootstrap in my plugin. What is the best way to include? I couldn't find anything related to this, so far I have found several  bootstrap plugin, which I dont need, I need to include some js and css element from bootstrap in my plugin. I am new to bootstrap.

Also I have tried something similar like including in WP theme, but it doesn't work?

If you need more information, please ask me, I will provide you

I have tried to include something similar to WP theme in the main file, index.php this :

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hi there, welcome to stackoverflow. It would help if you could share a little more about what you have tried and how it has failed. 

Depending on your plugin, it might be worth to reference a copy of boostrap via a CDN

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using Twitter Bootstrap together with Wordpress](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11527723/using-twitter-bootstrap-together-with-wordpress)

Comment: @JasonNathan i have update the question, i am not able to copy code in coment.  I need to use bootstrap elements inside of the plugin, when I activate, to have it already there. I dont want to depend on the others plugin, or if the client have bootstrap on this site.

Answer (score 19):

You need to use `wp_register_script()` and then `wp_enqueue_script()` for js.

You need to use `wp_register_style()` and then `wp_enqueue_style()` for css.

See the following js example...

```
wp_register_script('prefix_bootstrap', '//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js');
wp_enqueue_script('prefix_bootstrap');
```

And now do the same for the css...

```
wp_register_style('prefix_bootstrap', '//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css');
wp_enqueue_style('prefix_bootstrap');
```

It's a good idea to place these in a reusable method in case you will be using ajax. This way, you don't need to relist every script or stylesheet within the ajax methods.

```
function prefix_enqueue() 
{       
    // JS
    wp_register_script('prefix_bootstrap', '//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js');
    wp_enqueue_script('prefix_bootstrap');

    // CSS
    wp_register_style('prefix_bootstrap', '//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css');
    wp_enqueue_style('prefix_bootstrap');
}
```

The use of the "prefix_" will help prevent conflicts and save you some trouble in the long run.

Comment: "This way you can just call the function whenever you need it." <- this may lead to some kind of a design flaw, isn't it? adding these files too often will impact the site's performance heavily..

Comment: @MartinPfeffer I'm not sure what design flaw can exist from calling a function "whenever you need it". Perhaps this could be interpreted as needing to call the function multiple times within the same page load, however I was simply referring to the possibility that Bootstrap may not be needed in all circumstances and if you don't "need" it, don't call the function.

Comment: Maybe it was the "just" what gave me a sceptical feeling. btw: prefix_enqueue() is rather a method than a function :) … However, your answer is right, it is worth the upvote.

Comment: @MartinPfeffer you are correct in the method vs function argument and have me there. I will correct the statement.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the 'wp_head' action to add code to the header of the site each time the page loads. Put something like this into your plugin:

```
    add_action('wp_head','head_code');

function head_code()
{

$output = '<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>';    
$output .= '<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>'; 
$output .= '<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>';

echo $output;

}
```

Comment: I think the asker meant to have bootstrap included in the admin area for the plugin, that's why when he/she tried to include it in the index.php file it didn't work. So admin_enqueue_scripts action needs to be used to include scripts and styles in the admin area. 

Also jquery is part of standard WP installation. And this one bootstrap.min.css is needed too, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Use bellow code in your plugins main PHP file. "wp_print_styles" action hook includes CSS styles. "wp_print_scripts" action hook includes java script. Use these two hooks to include Bootstraps Javascript and Style sheets in the plugin.

```
 add_action( 'wp_print_styles', 'add_my_plugin_stylesheet' );
 function add_my_plugin_stylesheet() {
wp_register_style('mypluginstylesheet', '/wp-content/plugins/postgrid/style.css');

wp_register_style('prefix_bootstrap', '//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css');
wp_enqueue_style('mypluginstylesheet');
wp_enqueue_style('prefix_bootstrap');
```

}

```
add_action('wp_print_scripts','add_my_plugin_js');
function add_my_plugin_js(){
wp_register_script('prefix_bootstrap', '//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js');
wp_enqueue_script('prefix_bootstrap');
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Just improving @zgr024's answer *(enable wordpress debug and you will see some errors with that answer)*, **because scripts and styles should not be registered until a wp_enqueue_scripts**.

So let's change the sentences order, as well as change `wp_enqueue_script` to `wp_enqueue_scripts`.

And finally, everything you need is here, in the most appropriate way:

```
<?php
wp_enqueue_scripts('prefix_bootstrap');
wp_register_script('prefix_bootstrap', '//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js');

wp_enqueue_style('prefix_bootstrap');
wp_register_style('prefix_bootstrap', '//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css');
```