# How do I properly include bootstrap in a plugin?

Tags: wordpress

I am working on a plugin that requires Bootstrap.

I am not sure how to include it so it does not conflict with any Bootstrap mark-up in the surrounding theme.

I found the thread below. No info there. In fact, it appears to end with the same question I needed to ask.

[SO post on this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24016321/how-to-include-bootstrap-in-wordpress-plugin-development)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's unfortunately no "no-conflict mode" for CSS files. There's also no guarantee you'll be able to detect whether or not Bootstrap is already loaded.

What you *could* do is either keep only the relevant bootstrap parts for your plugin, prefix the bootstrap selectors with something, or (most common) include Bootstrap with your plugin, but allow the user to decide whether or not to include it (via a custom meta value in the admin).

Comment: Thanks. I figured as much and thought I would have to resort to a setting to allow/disallow it.